# Servlet Called Twice

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

On my web application, which is hosted on Google App Engine, whenever I call a Servlet by typing in the URL on a browser, this results in two calls being made to the Servlet. However, if I make a call to the Servlet by clicking on an anchor, then only one call is made.

What is the cause and how can I correct this behavior?

Web.xml

```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>ServletOne</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.test.nz.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>ServletOne</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Servlet:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException 
    {
        final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyServlet.class.getName());
        log.info("Here in MyServlet");
    }
}
```

**Update:**

The issue appears to be caused by Google Chrome making requests on its own. Whenever I type in a URL, a request is made before I actually press enter, followed by the actual request. Is there any way to disallow these type of requests to my application?

Comment: Open your browser dev tools, click on the network panel, and see what happens.

Comment: The network panel only shows the Servlet being called once, but the logging shows that it resulted in two calls.

Comment: where is your html/jsp code also add the complete the web.xml ?

Comment: Do you have any html validator extension enabled in chrome browser.If yes disable it .If problem still persist post your servlet code here.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do not have an html validator extension enabled. I have seen the same behavior testing on several different devices with chrome browsers. I have added code for a simple Servlet I am testing with and I still see this happening.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, only in Chrome, turns out the servlet was mapped to / and was accepting requests for favicon.ico as well. For me this is the source of the second request.

Comment: Holy s... :D i would have never thought about that. Thanks.